# springboot+mybatis Exception : org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I got the following exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [pers.panxin.springboot.demo.mapper.UserMapper] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Controller :

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/userList")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getAllUser(){
        return "userList : "+userService.getAllUser().toString();//+list.toString();
    }

}
```

Service:

```
public interface UserService {

    public String getString();

    public List<User> getAllUser();

}
```

ServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userMapper;

    @Override
    public String getString() {
        return "something else ... ";
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUser() {
        return userMapper.getAllUser();
    }
}
```

Mapper Interface:

```
@Service
public interface UserMapper {

    /**
     * @return
     */
    public List<User> getAllUser();

}
```

Application's main class

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationStarter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationStarter.class, args);
    }

}
```

how the exception happened or something wrong in my code?

Comment: it 's a maven project created by IntelliJ IEDA   , springboot+mybatis

Answer (score 1):

1.
I am not sure if you are using [mybatis-spring](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/getting-started.html) library. If you are trying to integrate MyBatis with Spring you should use it. So make sure you have it as dependency.

2.
When you have mybatis-spring as dependency, just add this annotation to you configuration class:

```
@MapperScan("package.where.mappers.are.located")
```

It is because mybatis-spring has separate scanning for MyBatis mappers. Also you should remove `@Service` annotation from you mapper because if this separate mybatis-spring scanning.

EDIT:

As @Persia pointed out, you can use [mybatis-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-spring-boot) library to pull mybatis-spring dependency into your Spring Boot project.

Comment: mybatis-spring-boot-starter depends on mybatis-spring library

Comment: OK, wasn't aware of that library. Updated my answer

Comment: I'v solved this problem, just cause I did not have the config of mybatis, I thought it would auto scan the BeanMapper.xml  ,but it's not .

Comment: but, another problem occured . I tried to return the .jsp  and  referenced the example of springboot at the github . but it failed.

Comment: what's the new exception ?

Answer (score 0):

Get the same error today. Check the bean configuration  `org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer` and `org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean`. I mistyped the "`basePackage`" value for the former one, and the "`typeAliasesPackage`" value for the second one. After fixing the path, it works fine. Like this:

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="package.path.to.your.model"/>
    <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:mappers/*.xml"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="package.path.to.your.dao"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: thanks, I use springboot http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/   and without the configuration of XML, and I recommend to use with it, It would make it easier to create an application for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add MappedTypes along with @MapperScan with

Code looks like the below

@MappedTypes({UserMapper.class})

@MapperScan("package.where.mappers.are.located")